# output my javascript variable in a div

Tags: javascript, html

i want to output the javascript dayz variable into the results div, but its not outputting anything, when i try alert(dayz) after the calculation it does, but i want it to output the dayz variable the html.

..help

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My first JavaScript page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var calculation = function(){

    //days
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours_id").value;
    var d = 10000/hours;
    var da = 1000%hours;
    var dayz = d.toFixed(0);
    dayz = parseInt(dayz, 10);
    dayz = dayz + da;


    //years
    var years = days/365;
    years = years.toFixed(2);

    //weeks
    var weeks = days/7;
    weeks = weeks.toFixed(2);


    };

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=dayz;

    </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <form name="input">
        <input type="text" id="hours_id" name="hours_id">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="calculate" onClick="calculation()">  
    </form>



<div id="results"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=dayz; inside calculation function and try

Comment: Are there supposed to be two different variables? days and dayz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    function calculation(){

    //days
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours_id").value;
    var d = 10000/hours;
    var da = 1000%hours;
    var dayz = d.toFixed(0);
    dayz = parseInt(dayz, 10);
    dayz = dayz + da;
    //years
    var years = dayz/365;
    years = years.toFixed(2);
    //weeks
    var weeks = dayz/7;
    weeks = weeks.toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=dayz;

    };
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4MYGa/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following statement inside the function definition:

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = dayz;
```

like this:

```
var calculation = function () {
    //days
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours_id").value;
    var d = 10000 / hours;
    var da = 1000 % hours;
    var dayz = d.toFixed(0);
    dayz = parseInt(dayz, 10);
    dayz = dayz + da;
    //years
    var years = dayz / 365;
    years = years.toFixed(2);
    //weeks
    var weeks = dayz / 7;
    weeks = weeks.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = dayz;
};
```